# How to preview a PDF file before upload on a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, file-processing

I have an `<apex:inputFile />` for selecting a PDF file from system. After selecting the PDF file I want to view (watch) selected PDF. How can I do it. Please give me some idea for to do it?
thanks sir.

Comment: Somehow you have to upload the PDF. But you are leaving unclear what you want to do with it and in which context.

Comment: Sir i want to display my whole pdf file to user  before sending it to server for split pdf file.

Comment: what you intent to do is a client side operation which is not supported by visual force out of the box. Most likely you will find Javascript or Flash based solutions for that purpose, which you can use on your visualforce page.

Comment: what i can do it using <apex:iframe>.? If not then please give me some idea using javascript or any other technique for to do this work. Thanks sir

Comment: probably not, since in the iframe you'll have to have the PDF uploaded already. I would suggest an other approach.

Comment: I can give the path of selected pdf file in src then it is possible or not sir?

Comment: Use an iframe src to a local path? Unlikely to be successful. But try it! My guess: it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to do it all client-side before you actually make the upload. I can not provide you full source for a solution, but I'll try to give some links which you can elaborate on your own.

You probably may have to acquire some deeper Javascript and technical knowledge, I guess.

First google for 'preview a PDF file before upload' start investigating this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851062/get-preview-of-uploaded-pdf-file-as-image-on-click-side
- http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/

Searching for 'javascript pdf viewer' you get alos some promising results:

- http://viewerjs.org/
- https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/